# Java RESTful Service with Jersey and ActiveMQ - loading Connection to ActiveMQ on Startup

Tags: java, web-services, rest, tomcat

I have a REST webservice with Jersey and Tomcat. If a Client calls the REST webservice, it will send a message to an ActiveMQ Queue Server. For this, the REST-server has to create a connection, a session and so on to send a message to the ActiveMQ service. At this time, every call from a client will create this connection and session and so on. Look at this example

```
    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    public Response getProducts() {
        ...
        session.start();
        connection.start();
        ...
        sendMessageToQueue();
        ...
        session.close();
        connection.close()

}
```

What i want is to create a class which represents a Messagehandler which already started the connection, session and so on. With `messageHandler.sendMessage()` it should be possible to send a message instantly from the REST getProducts Method.

My Problem is: How can i instantiate such a Handler which is always running when Tomcat server starts up?
I found that with implementing a ServletContextListener and Listeners, a class can be loaded before the Tomcat runs, but how can i access this in my REST-Servlet-Classes?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I found out how to solve my problem.
It can be done by using the idea with the ServletContexListener i talked about. Just implement the ServletContexListener and add it to the web.xml

```
 <listener>
  <listener-class>path.class</listener-class>
 </listener>
```

In the contextInitialized Method, the connection can be set up and started

```
@Override
public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent sce) {

ActiveMQConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new ActiveMQConnectionFactory(brokerUrl);

try {
    connection = connectionFactory.createConnection();
    connection.start();
    session = connection.createSession(transacted, ackMode);
    Destination destination = session.createQueue("queue");
    producer = session.createProducer(destination);

    ServletContext sc = sce.getServletContext();
    sc.setAttribute("ActiveMQSession", session);
    sc.setAttribute("ActiveMQProducer", producer);

} catch (JMSException e) {


}

}
```

With

```
    ServletContext sc = sce.getServletContext();
    sc.setAttribute("ActiveMQSession", session);
    sc.setAttribute("ActiveMQProducer", producer);
```

You set attributes globally, so you can access it by any other servlet. In my jersey case:

```
public class GetQuote {

    @Context ServletContext context;

    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    public Response getProducts() throws JMSException {

    MessageProducer producer = (MessageProducer) context
                .getAttribute("ActiveMQProducer");

    Session session = (Session) context.getAttribute(
            "ActiveMQSession");     

    }
```

The jersey architecture is just for using POJO's without extending HttpServlet or something else. If you use httpservlets, you may get the context over the getContext() function instead of the @Context annotation

Hope that helps somebody else.